# Sample code for converting TFS work item to XML?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I want to write a simple program to query TFS and convert all of the work items to a uniform type XML file and save them to separate files in a folder.

I'm sure this kind of work is commonly enough done, and is very simple - but I can find no samples on the Internet and no way of connecting to TFS programmatically and retrieving only work item info. Would anyone be able to help me out ?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    private TfsTeamProjectCollection GetTfsTeamProjectCollection()
    {
        TeamProjectPicker workitemPicker = new TeamProjectPicker(TeamProjectPickerMode.SingleProject, false, new UICredentialsProvider());
        workitemPicker.AcceptButtonText = "workitemPicker.AcceptButtonText";
        workitemPicker.Text = "workitemPicker.Text";
        workitemPicker.ShowDialog();
        if (workitemPicker.SelectedProjects != null || workitemPicker.SelectedProjects.Length > 0)
        {
            return workitemPicker.SelectedTeamProjectCollection;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private WorkItemCollection  WorkItemByQuery(TfsTeamProjectCollection projects, string query)  //query is likethis:SELECT [System.ID], [System.Title] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.Title] CONTAINS 'Lei Yang'
    {
        WorkItemStore wis = new WorkItemStore(projects);
        return wis.Query (query );
    }
```

**WorkItemCollection is what you want.** You can get WorkItems and their properties.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the TFS SDK.

You can find many tutorials on internet like this [one](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/07/10/tfs-2010-sdk-get-projects-iterations-area-path-queries-and.aspx).

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) will also help you too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [TFS SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) working with [work items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130347%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Then all you need to do is convert it into the format you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the query results as suggested by Lei Yang.
Then start building the XML.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
//XML declaration
XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null);
// Create the root element
XmlElement rootNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("WorkItemFieldList");
xmlDoc.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaration, xmlDoc.DocumentElement);
xmlDoc.AppendChild(rootNode);
 //Create a new element and add it to the root node
 XmlElement parentnode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("UserInput");
```

Iterate through all the workitem field values

```
xmlDoc.DocumentElement.PrependChild(parentnode);
//wiTrees of type WorkItemLinkInfo[] is the result of RunLinkQuery
foreach (var item in wiTrees)
{
int fieldcount = workItemStore.GetWorkItem(item.TargetId).Fields.Count;
while (fieldcount > 0)
{
//Create the required nodes
XmlElement mainNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement(workItemStore.GetWorkItem(item.TargetId).Fields[fieldcount -1].Name.ToString().Replace(" ", "-"));
// retrieve the text 
//Use the custom method NullSafeToString to handle null values and convert them to String.Empty 
XmlText categoryText = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(workItemStore.GetWorkItem(item.TargetId).Fields[fieldcount - 1].Value.NullSafeToString().ToString());
// append the nodes to the parentNode without the value
parentnode.AppendChild(mainNode);
// save the value of the fields into the nodes
mainNode.AppendChild(categoryText);
fieldcount--;
}

}
// Save to the XML file
xmlDoc.Save("widetails.xml");
```